# A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have seen previous issues here on it anyway, but I'm asking for the particular case at hand.

Currently trying to rename some files, but I actually want the file with the duplicate name to be overwritten.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /R %%A in ("tgt*.nif") do (
   set "fname=%%~A"
   call ren "%%fname%%" "%%fname:*tgt=%%"
)
pause
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: As suggested, an example. Well this is not real, but simply putting it (Reading this it's not "simply" but pft):

*I have two files, one which is TimeGoog.pdf and another which is Goog.pdf. Now I have these variations of these two files in many folders, so it may be TimeToot.pdf and Toot.pdf. I want to rename all the TimeGoog.pdf to Goog.pdf, deleting the old Goog.pdf at the same time as it's been overwritten.*

The script above does that, except because it's renaming to something that's already there, it won't do it. Note that the batch code I put above would work in the parent folder, and all the sub folders would take effect.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `move` command?

Comment: @MCND No I haven't. To be real here my knowledge of batch is trash. All I can say is that the current files I have are already in the folders they are needed to be in, as well as the previous file I'm trying to overwrite.

Comment: what are the duplicate names? What do they look like? Maybe an example in your post could help.

Comment: @J.Baoby I added a real...mess of an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /r %%A in ("tgt*.nif") do (
        set "folder=%%~dpA"
        set "fileName=%%~nxA"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            echo move /y "!folder!!fileName!" "!folder!!fileName:*tgt=!"
        endlocal
    )
    pause
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me : for renaming files with no extension, to files with a extension. (.csv)

`ren *.* *.csv` (wrong)

gives : A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found

`ren *.* *.*csv` (works)

Works.

Comment: won't that mean that `test.nif` becomes `test.nifcsv`?